# df.replace() not being converted into the text or csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

When I use:
    df = df.replace(oldvalue, newvalue)
it replaces the file, but when I try to put the new dataframe into either a text file or a csv file, it does not update and continues to be the original output before the replace.

I am getting the data from two files and trying to add them together. Right now I am trying to change the formatting to match the original formatting.

I have tried altering the placement of the replacement, as well as editing my df.replace command numerous times to either include regrex=True, to_replace, value=, and other small things. Below is a small sampling of code.

```
    drdf['adg'] = adgvals #adds adg values into dataframe 
    for column, valuex in drdf.iteritems():
        #value = value.replace('444.000', '444.0')
        for indv in valuex:
            valuex = valuex.replace('444.000', '444.0')
        for difindv in valuex: 
            fourspace = '    ' 
            if len(difindv) == 2:
                indv1 = difindv + fourspace
                value1 = valuex.replace(difindv, indv1)
            drdf = drdf.replace(to_replace=valuex, value=value1)

    #Transfers new dataframe into new text file
    np.savetxt(r'/Users/username/test.txt', drdf.values, fmt='%s', delimiter='' )
    drdf.to_csv(r'/Users/username/089010219.tot')
```

It should be replacing the values (for example 40 with 40(four spaces). It does this within the spyder interface, but it does not translate into the files that are being created.

Comment: Try using `map` with a dictionary instead of replace.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it with `map`:

```
drdf['adg'] = adgvals #adds adg values into dataframe 
   for column, valuex in drdf.iteritems():
       #value = value.replace('444.000', '444.0')
       for indv in valuex:
           valuex = valuex.map('444.000':'444.0')
       for difindv in valuex: 
           fourspace = '    ' 
           if len(difindv) == 2:
               indv1 = difindv + fourspace
               value1 = valuex.map(difindv:indv1)
           drdf = drdf.replace(valuex,value1)

#Transfers new dataframe into new text file
np.savetxt(r'/Users/username/test.txt', drdf.values, fmt='%s', delimiter='' )
drdf.to_csv(r'/Users/username/089010219.tot')
```

Comment: Maps use series instead of actual dataframes. This doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```py
df.replace(old, new, inplace=True)
```

Inplace essentially puts the new value 'inplace' of the old in some cases. However, I do not claim to know all the inner technical workings of inplace.

Comment: The inplace=True keeps assigning my dataframe as a NoneType:                                          AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'                                                           if len(difindv) == 2:
                    indv1 = difindv + fourspace
                    valuex = valuex.replace(difindv, indv1)
                drdf = drdf.replace(valuex, inplace=True)

Comment: Hmm not sure. Sounds to me like you might be trying to manipulate DataFrames in an odd spot of the code, and you are losing the correct reference. I might throw some ```print(df.head())```'s through out the code to check and see where your frames change.

Comment: Another note, you definitely have a lot of stuff looping on top of other stuff. (3 for loops and an if statement). I highly doubt it takes that much code to make values uniform especially in Python - I would look for other options with less loops. You are less likely to lose a reference. Best of luck.